# Sudoku Solver code gives unexpected result

Tags: c++, recursion, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

Question Link: https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-sudoku/description/

Below is my code for Sudoku Solver.
I am expected to return true if the sudoku is solvable else false.

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool solveSudoku(vector<vector<char>> &board, int row, int col) {
        // If the position is now at the end of the 9*9 grid
        if(row == 8 and col == 9) return true;
        // if column has reached upper bound
        if(col==9)  {
            row++;
            col=0;
        }
        // For characters other than dot move to the next position
        if(board[row][col]!='.') return solveSudoku(board,row,col+1); 
        for(int i=1; i<=9; i++) {
            char num='0'+i;
            if(isValid(board, row, col, num)) {
                board[row][col]=num;
                if(solveSudoku(board,row,col+1)) return true;
            }
            board[row][col]='.';
        }
        return false;
    }
    bool isValid(vector<vector<char>> &board, int row, int col, char num) {
        int i,j;
        /* Checking if its duplicated on the same row */
        for(i=0; i<9; i++) {
            if(i!=col && board[row][i] == num) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        /* Checking if its duplicated on the same col */
        for(i=0; i<9; i++) {
            if(i!=row && board[i][col] == num) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        /* Checking if its duplicated inside the 3*3 grid */
        int rowOffset=row-(row%3);
        int colOffset=col-(col%3);
        for(i=0; i<3;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<3;j++) {
                if((rowOffset+i)!=row && (colOffset+j)!=col && board[rowOffset+i][colOffset+j] == num) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    bool isValidSudoku(vector<vector<char>>& board) {
        if(solveSudoku(board, 0, 0)) return true;
        return false;
    }
};
```

for the below test input

```
[[".","8","7",  "6","5","4",  "3","2","1"],
 ["2",".",".",  ".",".",".",  ".",".","."],
 ["3",".",".",  ".",".",".",  ".",".","."],

 ["4",".",".",  ".",".",".",  ".",".","."], 
 ["5",".",".",  ".",".",".",  ".",".","."],
 ["6",".",".",  ".",".",".",  ".",".","."],

 ["7",".",".",  ".",".",".",  ".",".","."],
 ["8",".",".",  ".",".",".",  ".",".","."],
 ["9",".",".",  ".",".",".",  ".",".","."]]
```

Note: This is a leetcode question

It returns false which I feel is correct but the expected answer is true. How is this supposed to be a wrong Answer.
Could anyone pls explain.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A note on the information content in the title: Would you be asking this question if you got the expected result?

Comment: How do you know the expected answer is true?  If I'm interpreting your test input correctly, that sudoku is unsolvable because it would require two `1`s in the first row or two `9`s in the first column.

Comment: This is a leetcode question

Comment: What is the source of the "expected answer true"? Ask them. Because, assuming that I (slightly daringly) formatted appropriatly for the structure of input, I really agree with "unsolvable". Actually the input seems specifically designed to be unsolvable....

Comment: Are you perhaps misinterpreting the leetcode output?  Maybe it is expected to be `false` and your solver returns `true`.

Comment: Recommendation: Add a `main` that feeds the input into the question so you have something closer to a [mre] that we can all run and play around with.

Comment: I have added the question link in the question, pls check

Comment: I did. The link does not show your example (and does not give an expected answer for it, obviously). Or did I miss something?

Comment: The link just contains the question, Added it for your reference

Comment: Yes. Now please link the source of the shown example along with its expected result.

Comment: My reading from the link is that you are supposed to determine if the given board is valid, not actually solve anything.

Comment: @Yunnosch "Only the filled cells need to be validated" so it's valid (now) even if it's not solvable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the task.

> Determine if a 9 x 9 Sudoku board is valid. Only the filled cells need to be validated according to the following rules:

The filled cells do NOT violate Sudoku's rules.